# Cannot add service reference

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web-service, specifically:

http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v4/AffiliateService?wsdl

However - after using the standard Webservices dialog to add a service reference - none of the operations are available on the generated classes - it's just empty:

[image: Empty sadness]

I've tried changing all different combinations of options on the 'add reference' dialogue.

Is there another approach to adding references of this type?

(note: in order to actually invoke the operations, the service is expecting a username/password header - Perhaps I need to include that whilst generating the classes? If so - how?)

Comment: I wonder if the problem is with the web service provider?  When I go to the WSDL of a web service I built, the XML pops up in the browser.  When I go to the URL you have posted in the question, the browser doesn't know what to do with it and asks me if I want to open the file or download it, and when I said open, it asked what application I wanted to use.

Comment: From the header of your URL: "Content-Type: application/wsdl+xml"  From the header of my URL: "Content-Type: text/xml"

Comment: The underlying problem is that AffiliateWindow's WSDL doesn't conform to the [WS-I Basic Profile](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html) and that's why VS chokes on it. The "Add Service Reference" and "Add Web Reference" dialogs -- and the corresponding `svcutil` and `wsdl` command-line tools -- tolerate quirks in slightly different ways. In this case it looks like `wsdl.exe` can handle it, as described in [Black Frog's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32616834/55847) below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the [Web Services Description Language Utility (Wsdl.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to generate the proxy class manually.

> ```
> wsdl http://api.affiliatewindow.com/v4/AffiliateService?wsdl /namespace:AffiliateWindow
> ```

I like using **namespace** option so none of the objects with have a conflict with my current solution.

[image: wsdl command line]

Then I can add the resulting code file to your solution.  I have attached a screenshot of the Object Browser from the solution:

[image: object browser]

Now, you can instantiate the service as you wish:

```
// I don't know anything about Affiliate Window - but I am assuming you would use it
// like the following code below

AffiliateWindow.UserAuthentication auth = new AffiliateWindow.UserAuthentication();
auth.sType = AffiliateWindow.UserType.affiliate;
auth.sPassword = "123456";

AffiliateWindow.ApiService svc = new AffiliateWindow.ApiService();
svc.UserAuthenticationValue = auth;
```

Comment: This worked a treat. You're my hero. make sure you use the bounty money to buy something fun.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that some SOAP references (like SalesForce) have to be added as a Web Reference instead of a regular Service Reference.

When you right-click on References, Add Service Reference, then click the Advanced button at bottom, then the Add Web Reference... button at bottom.
If you enter a valid endpoint URL, it should display the Web Services available for referencing in the list on the right side of the dialog.